# Критика через инспекцию кода

Tags: обсуждение, синонимы-меток, инспекция-кода

Обнаружилась такая метка как [критика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0). По сути это [инспекция-кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0). Предлагаю засинонимизировать.

Comment: Там один вопрос же только, зачем синонимизировать? Проще же заменить.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov и что теперь каждый раз менять? Вопроса было два на момент моей публикации. Если кто-то решил назвать инспекцию критикой, то вполне вероятно это повторится. При наличии синонима проблема разрешится автоматически, переназначение же требует ручного труда на регулярной основе.

Comment: @älёxölüt, ну что-то мне не кажется оно синонимом...

Comment: @Qwertiy а мне кажется. Кто прав?

Comment: @älёxölüt, тот кто может забанить :)

Comment: @Grundy бан за критику. Как это банально. Нет чтобы за инспекцию кода.

Comment: @Qwertiy, тогда может приведёте пример, когда одно может использоваться без другого на _этом_ сайте?

Comment: @ixSci, а я не говорил, что оно вообще должно использоваться ;)

Comment: @ixSci кстати, тут пришла мысль, что если в вопросе нет кода, а, например, есть алгоритм, то "инспекция-кода" будет выглядеть странно.

Comment: @älёxölüt, а мы тут ещё и алгоритмы обсуждаем? Тогда тег должен быть инспекция-алгоритма, я полагаю.

Comment: @ixSci думаете, обсуждение алгоритмов будет оффтопом?

Comment: @älёxölüt, ну, у нас тут и так свалка, потому что плебеям не разрешают разные сайты, поэтому я бы не стал их считать вне тематики. Но сколько у нас таких вопросов? Т.е. в теории подобная коллизия возможна, но на практике мы вряд ли это увидим.

Comment: @ixSci вот на практике и дропнули метку "критика" :-D будем ждать новых вопросов.

Answer (score 5):

Я за то, чтобы сделать синонимом. Одну метку я вчера снял с вопроса в очереди проверок, оставив только инспекцию кода, но этой темы на мете ещё не было или я не посмотрел.

Никакого смысла для "критики" вне инспекции кода я не вижу.

Comment: PS Я видел комментарий Квертия, что ему НЕ кажется синонимом. Если будут какие-то конкретные аргументы помимо "я так вижу" -- будет очень неплохо увидеть их отдельным вопросом, чтобы можно было ознакомиться и выразить через upvote/downvote своё мнение.

Comment: Я согласен с Qwertiy, вот у меня аргумент в том, что критика — это обратная связь. Но ведь любой вопрос неявно подразумевает, что требуется обратная связь. Получается мета-метка, толку от которой нет. А вот с поспешным выводом, что для [критики] требуется [инспекция-кода], я не согласен.

Answer (score 3):

Я против того чтобы делать эти метки синонимами. Даже с учетом того [критика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0) сейчас выпилена. Давайте не будем забывать что с запросом не критику может придти вопрос без кода или вообще не касающийся конкретно программирования. Темы для вопросов несолько шире. См. [help/on-topic]

Comment: Я об этом как раз писал в [комментарии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8291/%d0%9a%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0/8363#comment34247_8291)

Comment: @älёxölüt Алгоритм еще как-то можно "за уши притянуть" к инспекции, а вот если вопрос про настройку nginx например или что-то что вообще кода не сильно касается

Comment: И какого рода [критика] тут может подразумеваться?

Comment: @älёxölüt Ну гипотетически некто может создать вопрос, в котором приведет свое решение и попросит критически его оценить на предмет соответствия современным практикам и поставленной задаче